# Logback losghstash appender add own field

Tags: logstash, logback

I need to send application logs directly to logstash using: Logstash Logback Encoder from multiple microservices. Problem is that when I am sending logs logstash recive logs like this:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2021.01.21-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "id",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1.6928859,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2021-01-21T14:13:05.480Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "message",
    "host": "gateway",
    "port": 43892
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-01-21T14:13:05.480Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "message": [msg]
  },
  "sort": [ sort ]
}
```

I need to add a custom field in "fields" section or in general section. Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: if you want to do in logstash, you can use the filter common option [add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field)

Comment: @Baudsp i dont have logstash file, I am using logback appender

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) filter in your logstash configuration file.

For example, into logstash configuration your file, this looks like this :

```
filter {
  mutate { add_field => { "field_name" => "field_value" } }
}
```